# When using Django the save() function does not work using model forms

Tags: python, django, sqlite, save

Im trying to learn Django. I believe my form is working properly but the data is not saved into the database.

This is my model:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class parameters(models.Model):
    interval_1 = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    interval_2 = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    interval_3 = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    interval_4 = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    interval_5 = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    interval_6 = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    cost_1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    cost_2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    cost_3 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    cost_4 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    cost_5 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    cost_6 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
```

This is my form:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm

from .models import parameters

# Create your forms here.

class set_parameters(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = parameters
        fields = "__all__"
```

This is my view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from .models import parameters
from .forms import set_parameters

def frequence_create_view(request):
    form = set_parameters(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        print(request)
        print(form)
        form = set_parameters()
    else:
            print (form.errors)

    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'settings/settings.html', context)
```

These are my templates:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block frequence %}
    {% endblock %}
    {% block cost %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>

{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block frequence %}
<form action='.' method='POST'> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type='submit' value='save' />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

And this is my URL's

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from settings.views import frequence_create_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('frequence_create/', frequence_create_view),
]
```

The problem I have is that when i submit the form the information is not stored in the database.

Can somebody try to explain what the problem is?

Comment: have you seen any form errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct your code as shown, which will handle the get request too

```
def frequence_create_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = set_parameters(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = set_parameters()
    return render(request, 'your.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses. I realize my code actually did work, i saw my entries in the database when using the sqlite command line tool. I do however not see my entires in the admin GUI. Thank you bmons for your code suggestion which also works .